# Show one view if an NSUserDefault value is not set and another view if it is

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to ios development and I am going to store the users birthday in an NSUserDefault NSdate object.  Lets call that variable userBirthday

When the application loads I want to check if userBirthday is set.  If it is not set I want to show the setup view.  If it is set I want to show the other view.

How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    if (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("birthDay") != nil)
    {
        //do whatever you want to do when birthday is set
    }
    else
    {
        //present the view for setting birthday and set using:
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(userBirthday, forKey: "birthDay")
    }
```